# Why does this script call the server twice?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I hope this is enough code to identify the problem - I've been hitting my head against a wall trying to figure this out. It's Javascript from the popup part of a Chrome extension.

```
$('#save').click(function() {
    var baseURL = 'http://example.com/endpoint?';
    baseURL += 'a=' + encodeURIComponent($('#a').val());
    baseURL += '&b=' + encodeURIComponent($('#b').val());
    baseURL += '&c=' + encodeURIComponent($('#c').val());
    baseURL += '&d=' + encodeURIComponent($('#d').val());
    if ($('input#private').is(':checked')) {
        baseURL += '&private=true';
    }
    $('#form').css('display', 'none');
    $('#loader').fadeIn(500, function() {
        $('#popup-load').load(baseURL, function() {
            window.close();
        });
    });
});
```

I've checked and the button (`#save`) is not being clicked twice (added `alert` debug code), could it be that there's a bug on the server side?

Comment: I don't see any code where the actual call is performed?

Comment: @KGChristensen It's the `.load()` invocation that triggers the request.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that function. @Alfo, have you tried to drop the fadeIn() for testing?

Comment: Nah, didn't fix it I'm afraid.

Comment: Is your `.click` event somehow getting bound twice?  Do you have a jsfiddle reproducing this?  This code block doesn't appear to be the problem.

Comment: Better put in a fiddle. Also i think you should add "return false;" before closing the click function : return false; });

Comment: Would you mind explaining why that's a good idea? I thought that only applied to forms.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by creating a global flag, and invalidating it on the first run. This is checked each call. Dirty, but did the job.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var firstRun = true;

    $('#element').load(function() {
        if (firstRun) {
            firstRun = false;
            // Rest of your code
        }
    }
</script>
```